# Generate difference between 2 tables listing columns from both tables

Tags: oracle

Have 2 tables with same columns and want to generate the difference between the tables and want to show the difference listing all columns from both tables

example:

```
select a.*,b.* from (
    (
        select a.col1,a.col2 from 
        (select col1, col2 from table1 minus select col1, col2 from table2) as a
    )
    union
    (
        select b.col1, b.col2 from
        (select col1, col2 from table2 minus select col1, col2 from table2) as b
    )
)
```

The result should be

```
a.col1 a.col2 b.col1 b.col2

a.FName a.ZipCode          b.FName b.ZipCode
John    <same value>       Jane    <same value as A>
Alpha   1234               Beta    2345
```

My query returns exception that it is missing R parenthesis after the 1st minus keyword

Comment: In the top half of your union you use columns from a table alias `a` but don't define that alias anywhere. Ditto `b` in the second half of the union. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Thanks for that info . updated alias

Comment: a and b have two columns each. When you do the union, you get a result set with two columns, and there is no more "a" and "b" -  there is just the result of the union, which you did not give an alias to. And then you seem to do a cross join of a and b - that makes no sense. How do you get separate columns for a and b after you put them together with union?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find rows from table a which are missing in table b and rows in table b which are missing from table a. However, there is no point in joining these two sets. Try the following query and see if it works for you.

```
    SELECT col1, col2, 'Missing from table 2' title
    FROM
    (
    SELECT col1,
           col2 
    FROM   table1
    MINUS
    SELECT col1, 
           col2 
    FROM   table2
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1, col2, 'Missing from table 1' title
    FROM
    (
    SELECT col1,
           col2 
    FROM   table2
    MINUS
    SELECT col1, 
           col2 
    FROM   table1
    )
```